# Node re-connection problems

Tags: node

I am having a little bit of trouble with my node and would appreciate some help.

I have been baking flawlessly on my old macbook pro running ubuntu many months, but since there was one miss last week, I decided check what was happening. Effectively, virtualbox did not respond and I had to restart ubuntu. Still, I had my last verification yesterday, so things could not be too bad.

I run, as usual, `nohup ./tezos-node run --rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8732 &` to get the node back online, but I am nothing is happening for almost an hour, that is, ./tezos-client bootstrapped tells me that it cannot connect to the node. In fact, it gives me the following output:

```
"Warning: failed to acquire the protocol version from the node" and "Error: Rpc request failed".
```

The reason seems to be in both cases:

```
"Unable to connect to the node: connection refused"
```

I also checked the system reports, tezos-node is up and running but only consume 2% CPU, so it looks dead to me. Internet is working (Ethernet connection), I am logging into the computer via TeamViewer right now. Finally, I have been checking the lock.mdb and data.mdb files. The lock.mdb file was generated when I restarted the node, but the data.mdb file is not updating, which suggests to me again that I am having connection issues.

I could try restarting, but my guess is that I would only end up in the same spot again. Maybe I should try to manually connect to some nodes, but I am not sure about that and which to choose in case. Finally, maybe I am just not understanding the situation at all.

Comment: Have you tried to do a:
cd tezos && git checkout mainnet && git pull && make build-deps && eval $(opam env) && make clean && make

And tried it again?

Comment: This sounds like rebuilding to me, which should not be necessary. But it is certainly an option if I fail. At the moment, I am hesitant to do it though.

Answer (score 4):

You need to supply an initial list of peers for bootstrapping. Use the following parameter to supply one or more peers when starting the node:

```
./tezos-node config update --peer=IPADDR:PORT --peer=...
```

You can find a list on [tzscan](https://zeronet.tzscan.io/network) or use at least `--peer=boot.tzbeta.net`